# Branch of medicine that systematically considers human enhancement and morphological modification

Tags: computers, reference-request, implant, morphology

There are known implants, body modification, gene therapy (especially for the fans of morphological freedom), brain-computer interfaces and so on. But is there branch of medicine (some professional association, some peer-reviewed journal) that systematically considers human enhancements with such morphological improvement. E.g. with the advent of Artificial General Intelligence and with the ever increasing workload on the human physical and mental skills (business competition is very harsh today) some people my opt for such morphological improvement, like injections in muscles, like some implants, like brain connectivity to the cloud computing and memory resources. So - is there branch of medicine and community that consider such questions.

I know from my experience that the Stack community usually is very conservative and do not receive well futuristic questions that is why I need to mention the following: 1) there is professional society with it journal and annual conference for the human/superhuman level Artificial General Intelligence; 2) there is SENS research foundation and Methusaleh Venture fund for fighting the aging and there is journal "Rejuvenation Research"; 3) there is Transhumanist parties around the world that propose indefinite life extension, morphological freedom and superhuman evolution. So - all this is happening outside the medicine already. My question is - what about medical science?

Comment: Not sure why you think SE isn't open to futuristic questions. Perhaps you've never visited World Building? It's not that the community is conservative and closed to such questions. It's a matter of where you ask. Futuristic questions tend to be speculative, and speculative questions aren't usually welcome on sites that expect factual, well supported answers, which is most (but not all) of them. Speculative questions are probably better suited to discussion forums rather than Q&A sites like SE.